# how to put a border-bottom some px under a li tag

Tags: html, css, border

I am using a menu with dynamic content.
When click on a li tag, the tag gets the class "active". 
To see which class is active i put a border-bottom under it (3px grey)
How can i achieve that the border-bottom of 3px is , lets say, 5 px under the li tag instead of exactly staying at the bottom like below:

[image]

```
li.active {  
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333; /* grey border */ 
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Post updated: https://jsfiddle.net/L7haqtsv/58/

Comment: Please reduce the code in the Fiddle to the [mcve] code necessary to reproduce your problem (there's far more CSS than necessary); and then *include that [mcve] code in your question.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
 li.active::after{
   content:'';
   display:block;
   margin-top:5px;
   margin-left:15px;
   width:138px;  
   border-bottom: 3px solid #333;  
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5kn63z1r/

Comment: I agree. The pseudo element does the job. Thank you. Great solution

Answer (score 1):

Try adding more padding-bottom to your active item, I think that will achieve what you want. It worked for me with:

```
li.active { border-bottom: 3px solid #333; padding-bottom:30px; }
```

Comment: It doenst work for me. See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/L7haqtsv/65/

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted, it's now under the li as opposed to being a part of it. You can increase the border size to make it thicker and increase/decrease padding to adjust the position.

Comment: If you want there to be a gap between the element and the border (a white gap) then I would suggest using an after psuedo element like: `li.active::after{content:"";  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:3px;
  background:#333;
  margin-top:-5px;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **::after pseudo element** to add content and place it: 
I copied a piece of your code, not all, but it shows the border 5px below:

This is the part I've modified:

```
li.active {
  position: relative; // Add position: relative 
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333; /* grey border */ 
}

li.active:after {  
  position: absolute; // position your pseudo element
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333; /* grey border */  
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -8px; // Adjust here the distance
  left: 0;
}
```

The rest of the code here:

```css
.nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus, .nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  
}
.nav>li>a:focus, .nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
}
.nav-tabs {
  border: none !important;
}

body {
  background-color: #e9ebee;
}
.header {
  
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #4b4f56;
  padding: 15px 0 40px 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
}
.header-icons, .header-text {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.header-icons {
  font-size: 28px;
}
.inbetween {
  width: 100%;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.content {  
  padding: -1px 0 0 20px !important;
  border-radius: 4px !important;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px 30px 15px;
}
.tab-content {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;  
}

/* lintjes */
.green {
  background-color: #019f0c;  
}
.yellow {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: #eedc08;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.red {
  background-color: #dd0000;
}
.white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #1a5bdd;
}
.green, .yellow, .red, .white, .blue {
  height: 30px;
  width: 17%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px #000000;
}

#green-ribbon, #yellow-ribbon, #red-ribbon, #white-ribbon, #blue-ribbon {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#green-ribbon {
  background-color: rgba(1, 159, 12, 0.1);
}
#yellow-ribbon {
  background-color: rgba(254, 235, 9, 0.2);
}
#red-ribbon {
  background-color: rgba(230, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#white-ribbon{
  background-color: #fff;
}
#blue-ribbon {
  background-color: rgba(30, 105, 255, 0.1);
}

/* header kleuren*/
.green-header {
  color: #019f0c;
}
.yellow-header {
  color: #fec909;
}
.red-header {
  color: #e60000;
}
.white-header {
  color: #4f515a;
}
.blue-header {
  color: #1e69ff;
}
li.active {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333; /* grey border */ 
}

li.active:after {  
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333; /* grey border */ 
  width: 100%;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active green"><a href="#green-ribbon">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="yellow"><a href="#yellow-ribbon">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="red"><a href="#red-ribbon">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="white"><a href="#white-ribbon">&nbsp;</a></li>
        <li class="blue"><a href="#blue-ribbon">&nbsp;</a></li>
      </ul>
```